# problem with ubuntu startup

Tags: 12.04, lenovo

Sometimes my Ubuntu gets stuck with purple screen, and the only way to get out of that is a reboot. I have enabled verbose mode in grub2, but I see nothing on the screen.

Or sometimes in low resolution mode.

However, sometimes it boots correctly and prints all the things at startup.

And sometimes it gets stuck after printing "detecting usb number 3..."

My system is a Lenovo u410 with Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed bumblebee, and it works fine (I tried it with optirun). I have checked the pci devices, and both my graphic cards are known. I think there is a problem with my usb 3.0

Comment: Is it the same without bumblebee?

Comment: Yes, It is. I should restart several times to finally come up with a clean boot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled my ubuntu again. And this time I did not install mesa-utils. (for showing my intel GPU name in system details)
After that I installed bumblebee to support optimus technology. And now I can run "optirun" fine and my ubuntu starts normally.

I am going to update packages. If the problem appear again I will enable this question again.

Thanks

Comment: Glad it's fixed - i had exactly same issue and then i just reinstalled - i suspected mechanig tweak tool to be the culprit but i was probably wrong

Comment: @Akmur So what is responsible for your problem?

Comment: Mmmh I am not sure, the only thing I know is that now I don't have that problem. Sorry I can't give more details.