# Black screen on boot nvidia optimus card

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Whenever I boot my screen comes up with a black screen with the same text as if I hit <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>.
My graphics card is an Nvidia Optimus card using Bumblebee. It also sometimes comes up with "This system is running in low graphics mode." Sometimes it will boot, but it takes multiple hard reboots.

This is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)  
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)  
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)  
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)  
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
```

Comment: Could you give a few more details following the commands in these url? http://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Reporting-Issues

Comment: Sorry i could't reply sooner, i was on a class trip and did not have my computer with me. The output is: baseboard-manufacturer= Dell Inc. baseboard-product-name= 09G8VY baseboard-version= A00 system-manufacturer= Dell Inc. system-product-name= Dell System Inspiron N7110 system-version= not specified bios-vendor= Dell Inc. bios-version= A07 bios-release-date= 09/28/2011 optirun -V= optirun (Bumblebee) 3.1
Copyright (C) 2011 The Bumblebee Project
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.

Comment: Do you remember if when you first installed ubuntu, before you performed software update, was booting trouble-free?

Comment: Yes it was booting trouble free. The display drivers are just giving me trouble after some amount of use.

Answer (score 3):

First, in order to access the terminal, boot up in recovery mode, then select root prompt. However, this will only mount the disk in read-only mode, so do this:

```
mount remount,rw /
```

This remounts the filesystem in rw-mode. Then, uninstall all your Nvidia stuff by doing this:

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Try booting then. If it still doesn't boot properly, I suggest backing up your files from the root prompt, and then reinstalling the system. If it does boot, reinstall the Nvidia stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This should fix it. (At least, it worked for me when I had these problems.)

Answer (score 2):

did you try to remove all special nvidia drivers?

1. Boot into fail-safe terminal mode or previous kernel version (if exist)
2. do `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current`
3. reboot
4. after boot-up try to update the system and carefully re-install nvidia drivers.

if this does not help, remove all nvidia staff by `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
I had similar behaviour after kernel update with different nvidia card and this allows me to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, see this [problem with ubuntu startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267684/problem-with-ubuntu-startup)
After I installed Ubuntu I only install bumblee and now everything works fine.

As you know the problem is from incomplete support for optimus technology on Ubuntu.